# act_as_fuzzy_search plugin install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, fuzzy-search

I want to install the plugin for fuzzy search. I searched a lot and came across:

https://github.com/iulianu/rails-fuzzy-search

In my model I have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
include FuzzySearch
act_as_fuzzy_search :name, :email
property :id, Integer, :serial => true
property :name, String, :nullable => false , :format => /^[^<'&">]*$/, :length => 32
property :email,String, :nullable => false , :format => /^[^<'&">]*$/, :length => 32
.....
.....
end
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
uninitialized constant User::FuzzySearch
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the README on that github page:

## Installation

NOTE! The following plugin is a prerequisite:
  script/plugin install git://github.com/blythedunham/eload-select.git
More details at http://www.snowgiraffe.com/tech/329/eager-loading-select-plugin-when-select-plays-nice-with-include/

Have you installed the prerequisite plugin?

Comment: yes, i did install according to the README and i get the error.